# action url not calling correct action method in liferay6.1?

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-6

I have developed a *liferay6.1 portlet* with *spring mvc* where i have two `drop down`'s(First option and second option) and a `text box`(enter a name) and a save `button`.

I am having two `ajax` request respective to each `drop down`. Say for example, for second *option drop down*, i have a `javascript` method where I frame the action url with a param called `action` with value in it like below

```
<portlet:actionURL portletMode='view'><portlet:param name='action' value='dropDownSelect'/></portlet:actionURL> .
```

Likewise, I have a `javascript` method for other `drop down` also where I am providing action url like

```
<portlet:actionURL portletMode='view'><portlet:param name='action' value='addAnotherOption'/></portlet:actionURL>.
```

When I click on save button, I am doing a form submit where I have framed a url without action param. like

```
<portlet:actionURL portletMode='view'></portlet:actionURL>.
```

So for each and every action, I have a different method in my `controller.java` which will receive this action request. For two action methods, I have annotation like

```
  @RequestMapping(params = "action=dropDownSelect")
```

on top of the method. For one action method alone, I just gave annotation like this

```
 @RequestMapping("VIEW")
```

My issue is often, action request with param is not getting received in correct method instead it is going to the method which have annotation as `@RequestMapping("VIEW")`.

I have used the same code in `liferay6.0` where I didnt face any issues like this but in `Liferay 6.1` , I am facing this issue frequently. Can anyone help me with issue?

Comment: you should use @ResourceMapping and <portlet:resourceURL> for ajax things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually we have migrated our application which has more than 70 portlets from liferay 6.0 to liferay 6.1. It will be tough to change each and every method in those portlets. Isn't there any other approach or any reason why this kind of behaviour is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was happening because for each action url which i frame in javascript has portletmode="view". BEcause of which , intermiteently, spring doesn't lookup to verify whether any action param is there or not, it by default called the action method which has @RequestMapping("VIEW"). To solve this, i modified my annotation like this,

@RequestMapping("VIEW")
@ActionMapping(params = "action=dropDownSelect") for all the methods which has params values to be mentioned in annotation.
 So that while going from javascript to controller, spring will check for portletmode= view plus the action param also.